# how to make vertices align in a circle

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am completely new to blender and I was practicing how to make clothing out of a base mesh. I am using a technique where you duplicate a portion of the base mesh and expand out on it, but the vertices are not exactly how I want them. How can I adjust the mesh so the arm, neck and body holes are circular? [image]Thank you!

Comment: In edit mode try Alt+Shift+S (to sphere) and move the mouse right/left to adjust the "to sphere" influence. But is that case, not sure that'll give a good result. Can be more simple to do it manually, per vertex.